Can a lateral join work using the Cross DB feature saved queries using pgsql\redash?
I am trying to optimize my queries and make pieces of code re-usable but cannot get a lateral join to work. Example I have code that creates a series start and end for 12 weeks.
I can paste this code in several different queries and lateral join to data to count events that are true in each week i.e. left join lateral (select sum(case when (created < intervals.end) then 1 else 0 end from data) Summary on true. Independently within a single DB this works fine.
If I wanted to change the 12 weeks to 26 or 52 in the future I need to go and modify each query.
But if I save the date range code as its own query (Query_111) and select * from data is (query_222) then try to lateral join redash fails at the lateral
select intervals.start
, intervals.end
, Summary.*
from query_111 intervals
left join lateral
(select
sum(case when (created < intervals.end) then 1 else 0 end) as active
sum(case when (closed > intervals.start) and (closed < intervals.end) then 1 else 0 end) as closed
from query_222
)  Summary on true
Am I asking too much of redash using a lateral join and the cross DB query feature? or is there another option?
I can make the lateral join function within the scope of a single DB when querying a specific table name. When I modify the same code to use saved queries it chokes on the lateral. I am a novice trying to operate up a level.
